# Query Records "where MyCustom__Date__c.Month()=1"

Tags: apex, soql, datetime, dynamic-soql, date

I want the records where MyCustom_Date__c month is = January. Where my field MyCustom_Date__C is formula field

```
lst="select Name from CustomObj__c where MyCustom__Date__c.month() = : 1"
```

Its giving me following error :

> unexpected token: ')' Error is in expression '{!showBirthdays}' in
>   page birthdaycal:birthdaycalender:
>   Class.Birthdaycal.BirthdayCalenderController.showBirthdays: line 88,
>   column 1
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has
>   been notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution

> Use CALENDAR_MONTH(MyCustom__Date__c)=1 instead of MyCustom__Date__c.month()=1

- Now your query will look like :

select Name,MyCustom__Date__c from Contact where CALENDAR_MONTH(MyCustom__Date__c)=1